# How can we save this question?

Tags: discussion

So this is an interesting question:

[What established Christian theology speaks to the question of whether or not God is contingent on his followers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25673/what-established-christian-theology-speaks-to-the-question-of-whether-or-not-god)

It really does hit at a very good question within theology, one that theologians spill a lot of ink trying to answer.  God's contingency seems like both an established and documented area of theology, but I'm not sure how to make this on-topic.

Does my edit make it on topic, or is it hopelessly a truth question?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure it's even about Christianity. That is actually more of a general, philosophical kind of question and calling it a Christian Theology does not make it one.

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure there is no Christian theology that basically says it's all not true anyway so if we all stopped believing then God would cease to exist. It's like Nietzsche kind of thing.

Comment: That said, I do like your answer to it.

Comment: I would disagree that it's only philosophical.  There are religious structures that can exist without "humans".  Scientology being an example.

Comment: @rpeg. The Philosphical off-topic close reason is the same as saying "It's not about Christianity, exclusively". That means it is more generic than Christianity.

Comment: It is specifically about Christianity because the crux is where does Christianity stand on this hypothetical scenario?  The answer will differ with different religions.  We should share our knowledge on where Christianity is positioned on this matter.  I frankly think the question just offends people.

Comment: @rpeg I'm not sure I understand your question then. There are plenty of "dead" religions that we know plenty about (Norse, Greek and Egyptian mythology). Do they still exist or not really seems like a philosophical/sociological question to me.

Comment: That's a good point.  I hadn't thought of that.  The point of my question was whether or not Christianity had more to say outside of the expectations of human existence.  Could it function outside of that in it's claims of post-life (heaven, angels, etc).  Is it still Christianity at that point?  Or does it cease to exist - at the level of Greek mythology - once humanity is gone.  That was my intention of the question.  For example, the Mormons seem to have a cosmology that discusses god status and seemingly can exist without earth humans.

Comment: Imagine if we could know all of the religions that are now extinct - there are probably more than we could count.  Think of extinct Christian denominations - another case of lost truths.  *I'm not saying that they were 100% truth, but I suspect truth stories have been lost.*

Comment: @rpeg No doubt, it is a very interesting topic. A fabulous conversation starter for all your theologically/philosophically minded friends. I would love to discuss this at length. But that is the issue; I think it is more of a discussion topic than a question. Start a chat room. I'll stop by for sure. Now it is interesting that you bring up Mormonism. You might have something there.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hopeless truth question based on a hypothetical idea - probably the worst type of truth questions.

The "religion" would fall away and become forgotten, but the real question is, "would God continue to exist".  How to prove it?  God always existed, Christianity didn't.  There could be a time when either humans do not exist OR humans will forget the religion.  However, God will exist.

Comment: @affablegeek Just read your answer and I think we agree.

Answer (score 0):

The intent of the question was not to be pose is "god" contingent.  Instead I'm asking if Christianity is contingent on humanity.  I understand that for some the answer is obvious and easy and from my perspective, it is not.